# Printing on Zebra iMZ320 (Objective-C + ZebraSDK + ZPL)

Tags: ios, printing, zebra-printers

I'm working on an app for iOS(Ojective-C) + Zebra iMZ320 and I need some help!

I'm using Zebra SDK method `-(void)sendZplOverBluetooth{}` to send the variable data to printer.

I've designed my label using ZPL at http://labelary.com/viewer.html. Please find the label code at the end of the question.

I could split my label in 3 parts:

- Fixed text - Shown in code
- Picture - Shown in code
- Variable text - not shown in code and to be sent using `-(void)sendZplOverBluetooth{}`

**My Questions:**

- How do I deal with my label parts? Should I split them in 2 (fixed and variable) or 3 (fixed text, picture and variable text) parts?
- How do I save the code I have on the printer?
- How can I get all parts together in order to print "one" label?
- I've notice some size limitation when using the `sendZplOverBluetooth{}`. What to do if my data get's larger than supported?

Thanks in advance!

**My Label:**

```
^XA
^PON
^MNN,N
^LL900
^FO0,0^GB576,180,4,B^FS
^FO210,10^GB0,160,2,B^FS
^FO15,20^GFA,3266,3266,23,,X07MFE,V01FFCK03FF8,V0FFO0FF8,U0FCQ03F,T0F8S03F,S07CI01E0F1EL03E,R03CI01FE1FDE003FI07C,Q01FJ01E01FCE003FFI0F,Q07803F01CE1FFE0078FI01E,P01C00FFC1FE1EFE0078F078078,P07800FBF1FC1E7E00IF0FE01E,O01EI0F0F1E01E3E00FFC0FF80F,O0380F07878E01E1E01FE03E7C01C,O0E07E0783CFFCE1E01E007F80C0F,N0380F803C3EFFE6I01E00FF83F81C,N0E007383F7C7M0C01EI07E0E,M01C003F80FF8P03EI0FF038,M03I03F04FCI01IFCI03FE01F381C,M0EI01F0FI01MF8007E07C1007,L01CJ0FFE007OFC00E0FJ018,L03K07F803IFJ01IFC001FJ01C,L0EK03F00FF8M03FF001EK06,L0CL0807FQ0FE01CK038,K018M03FR01F8M01C,K07N0F86Q063FN04,K0EM07E4T07EM03,J018L01F18S018FM038,J03M07EV0CFEL01C,J06L01F88U013FM06,J0EL03FW07EFCL07,J0CL078FW033EL03,I018L0F7EX0EFL018,I03L03CEY037CL0C,I07L07B8Y01DEL06,I0EK01F7g01E7L07,I08K03FEgG0FFCK03,0018K03BEgG0FDEK018,003L0FFEgG0FEFL0C,007K01FF2gG01FF8K0C,006K03DE2gH07FCK06,006K03BC2gH07DCK07,00CK07F8gI01EEK03,008K0F7gJ01FFK03,018J01DFgJ01FF8J018,03K01FEgK07DCK08,03K03BEgL01CK0C,07K07F8gK01FEK0C,06K0FF8gK0IF8J06,06K0FFgK01IFCJ06,04J01FFgK03IFEJ07,0CJ01DF8gJ0KF8I03,0CJ01FF8gI01KF8I03,08J03BgK01KFCI03,18J07CgH03E03JFC6I018,18J078gG0OF83I018,38J0F8N07Q0FC07LF038I08,3K0E8N07O03F8007KFE018I08,3K0E8N032K01IFEI07KFE008I0C,3K0F8O0FK07JFI03FCIFC00CI0C,3K0F8N03FK0KFC003F01FFC004I0C,3J01FCN01FJ01LF801E18CFE004I0C,7J01DF2M01FJ03NF8E7EE0F804I0C,7J01DF8M07F8I03MF862FEE01F06I04,7J01DFJ07IF0JFE3LFE1167EF0E3E3I04,7J01FF00LF877PFCFCF3DF8IFBI04,6J01FE1NF11PF8FE983F8FF8FI04,6J01LFC1MFC3LF8FE87FF8FF87I04,6J01LFC07KFE03LFCFD03FFCFF83I04,6J01LFC01KF801LFE7901FFCFF8J04,6J01LFC007IFE001MF8780FFC7F8J04,603B81LFC001IF8001OFC07FC3F80CC04,603F81LF8I07FFI01OFE03FE3F81FE04,71IF1LF8I03FEI01OFE01IF387FF84,71EFF1LFCI07FEI01OFE00JF877F84,70IF1LFC007C07E0019OF007IF87FF8C,307FC1LFC038I03801C7NF003IF83FF0C,307FE0LFC0CK0603C3NF001IF83FF0C,307FE0LFC38K0103C0IFE01FEI0IF03FF0C,307FC0LFE70F803F0C3C07FFC003EI07FF03FF0C,3K0MFC7070C0C2FC03FF8M07FEK08,38J0MF8C7110C21FC00FF8M03FEK08,18J07KFE087090E10FC007F804K03FEJ018,18J07KFC0800E00107C00FF806K07FCJ018,08J03KF80800E00103C01FF807K07FCJ038,08J03KF80800F00101E07FF003K07FCJ03,0CJ01KF00801900201E1IF801803FEFF8J03,0CJ01JFE00401180601E7IF801C0KF8J07,04K0JFC003040608003JF800F0KFK06,06K0JF8I0F803FI01JF800F0IFE3K06,07K07FFES07IFC007CIFC6K04,03K03IFCQ01FF1FC007E7FFCCK0C,03K03JF8J0EJ01E003CF001F9FF9CK08,018J01IFEK0FK0F007C7800FE3E18J018,008K0IFL06K0181F81C003FF03K038,00CK0E018J03F8J0303F80FI0FE06K03,006K0300EQ0C1FF8078003E0CK07,006K03003P0383FF801EI0E1CK06,007K01803CO0E07FF800FC00E18K0E,003J01IFCF8M03C3IFI07IFE3L0C,0018I03I03FF8K01E0IFEJ0JFEK018,I08I02J038FF8003E03IFEJ03FF1CK038,I0C0063IFC0C03IFE01JFCK0301I06007,I0601FI0F784031FE00KF8M0E001F806,I07078C00388C060460703IFM01C0039C0C,I03870C001D88180031C03FFCM0780038418,I0187K0F983I01F001FF8M0FI01FC38,J0E18J03E03J06I0FEM01CJ0F87,J0618J01E03J01I078M038J0206,J03M0703J01R0EM0C,J018L01C18I02Q038L018,K0CM0788I021FO0EM03,K06I0EI01F8I0EE0CM078I06I06,K03001DJ03CI0F004L03EJ03801C,K01C039CJ0F801C00CK01FK01C038,L0E0FF8J01F81I0CK0F8L0606,L0700FL07FJ0CJ03CM020C,L0380EM0FE001J03FO01C,M0C0CN07FC3003FEK01J038,M07Q01KF8L07EI0E,M01CI03CX0C6003C,N0EI076X0EF007,N03800F8X07F81C,N01E01CY03007,O0781CU03E00101E,O01E07I0EQ077J07,P0782I0F6P073I01E,P03CJ0FEL03C0073I03C,Q07I0196001C007C0073I0F,Q01E0018E001C0018003F0078,R07CI0C001E0018K03E,S0F800800720018J01F,T0F8J0620018I01F8,T01F8Q01F8,U03FCO03F8,V07FFM07FC,W07FFCI03FFC,Y0MF,gG07FE,,::^FS
^FO220,45^FB350,5,0,C,0^AAN,22,10^FH^FDEden Pet Respeito por voc_88, seu pet e o meio ambi_88nte. www.edenpet.com.br^FS
^CFA,20
^FO0,190^GB576,110,2,B^FS
^FO5,200^FH^FDN_a3mero do Atendimento...^FS
^FO5,225^FH^FDN_a3mero do Lacre.........^FS
^FO5,250^FH^FDN_a3mero do Contrato......^FS
^FO5,275^FH^FDN_a3mero do Certificado...^FS
^FO0,315^GB576,110,2,B^FS
^FO5,325^FDNome do Pet.............^FS
^FO5,350^FH^FDEsp_82cie do Pet..........^FS
^FO5,375^FH^FDRa_87a do Pet.............^FS
^FO5,400^FDPeso do Pet.............^FS
^FO0,440^GB576,160,2,B^FS
^FO5,450^FH^FDCrema_87_c6o Translado Tipo.^FS
^FO5,475^FH^FDCrema_87_c6o Urna Modelo....^FS
^FO5,500^FH^FDCrema_87_c6o Tipo...........^FS
^FO5,525^FH^FDCrema_87_c6o Modalidade.....^FS
^FO5,550^FH^FDCrema_87_c6o Servi_87o........^FS
^FO5,575^FH^FDCrema_87_c6o Local Coleta...^FS
^FO0,615^GB576,110,2,B^FS
^FO5,625^FH^FDCl_a1nica.............^FS
^FO5,650^FDMotorista...........^FS
^FO5,675^FH^FDPropriet_a0rio........^FS
^FO5,700^FH^FDRespons_a0vel Entrega.^FS
^FO0,740^GB576,160,2,B^FS
^FO5,750^FH^FDValor Crema_87_c6o..........^FS
^FO5,775^FH^FDValor Coleta............^FS
^FO5,800^FH^FDValor Urna..............^FS
^FO5,825^FH^FDValor Translado.........^FS
^FO5,850^FH^FDValor Servi_87o...........^FS
^FO5,875^FH^FDValor Total.............^FS
^FO0,920^GB576,700,2,B^FS
^FO5,930^FDFINANCEIRO^FS
^FO5,975^FDQuantidade de Pagamentos..^FS
^FO5,1010^FDParcela 1.................^FS
^FO5,1035^FDForma.....................^FS
^FO5,1060^FDValor.....................^FS
^FO5,1085^FDVencimento................^FS
^FO5,1135^FDParcela 2.................^FS
^FO5,1160^FDForma.....................^FS
^FO5,1185^FDValor.....................^FS
^FO5,1210^FDVencimento................^FS
^FO5,1260^FDParcela 3.................^FS
^FO5,1285^FDForma.....................^FS
^FO5,1310^FDValor.....................^FS
^FO5,1335^FDVencimento................^FS
^FO5,1385^FDParcela 4.................^FS
^FO5,1410^FDForma.....................^FS
^FO5,1435^FDValor.....................^FS
^FO5,1460^FDVencimento................^FS
^FO5,1500^FH^FDObserva_87_e4es...............^FS
^FO5,1650^FH^FB576,5,0,J,0^FDConfirmo minha responsabilidade pelo animal de estima_87_c6o e autorizo a realiza_87_c6o da crema_87_c6o deste animal conforme as condi_87_e4es discriminadas neste documento, ou conforme contrato da Cl_a1nica com o Eden Pet Cremat_a2rio Ltda.^FS
^FO330,1790^FD___________________^FS
^FO330,1810^FH^FDRespons_a0vel Entrega^FS
^XZ
```

Comment: Marcos Degni,

Can you share me your solution, please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer one of the questions you can send the label in three parts by using the image save command in the first two parts and image load in the last part to pull in the first two parts. These commands are ^IS and ^IL.

You could also combine all of that in a single send. You might be experiencing an issue with iOS in which there is a problem writing on the BlueTooth channel. To get past this you must increase a delay in the send command. On your printer connection class set TimeToWaitAfterWriteInMilliseconds to 60 or higher.

Comment: Hello Banno, tanks for your answers! I've already managed to upload and and print and image saved on the printer. How do I save the ZPL file in the printer? Which kind of file? How do I upload it? Can you help?  tsk...

Comment: Add ^DF to the ZPL format. When you want to recall it use ^XF. The ZPL manual has the full description on how to use thoses commands,

Answer (score 0):

Ok, that's my answers to my own questions:

1. I've splited my label in 3 parts: Picture, Fixed text and Variable text.
2. Saving the Picture and the Fixed text on the printer:

I've used Zebra Setup Utilities (Running on a Windows PC), Option Zebra Designer Fonts and Graphics Downloader to save my picture on the printer's flash memory.

For the Fixed Text I've used the following ZPL (example) code to save it on the printer's flash memory:

"^XA^DFE:FILENAME.ZPL^FO5,40^FDLine 1^FS^FO5,60^FDLine 2^FS^XZ"

This will print Line 1 @ position 5, 40 and Line 2 @ Position 5, 60. 
Find details on the ZEBRA ZPL Programing Guide.

This code might be sent to the printer either using Zebra Designer (I have't tested) or using Xcode + iOS Device (I'll coment below)

3) Getting everything together

Let's say we have:

1) image file named LOGO.PCX that we managed to save using Zebra Designer
 2) fixed text file named FILENAME.ZPL
 3) variable text: Marcos for line 1 and MUC DONG for line 2.

That would be the ZPL code we would send to the printer:

@"^XA^FO5,5^XGE:LOGO.PCX^XFE:FILENAME.ZPL^FS^FO10,40Marcos^FO10,60MUC DONG^XZ";

This should print the LOGO.PCS @ position 5, 5,FILENAME.ZPL code on it's own positions, and the names MARCOS AND MUC DONG on positions 10, 40 and 10, 60.

4) Sending the code from your iOS device.

There is a ZEBRA document (see link below) with a code for sending ZPL OR CPCL to a Zebra printer using iOS. I suggest you use it. You will also need to download and instal the zebra IOS SDK (see instructions in the same document). You may star using the example file since you won't have to spend any time importing frameworks (that you are going to need to do in your own project).

https://km.zebra.com/kb/index?page=content&id=WH122&actp=RSS

5) If you are finding problems you may add the following line to you code:

[((MfiBtPrinterConnection*)thePrinterConn) setTimeToWaitAfterWriteInMilliseconds:200];

Hope I've helped.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the nature of the label, you can use [zebra-toolkit](https://github.com/diegoCath/zebra-toolkit) which will save you a lot of trouble with ZPL.